# Can you get a pulse value from txt file into a Shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, pulse

thanks for helping out!

I want a shell script to read the last value from a txt file. I've got this (another script) working from a python script, but this does not work in a shell script. I found some helping script parts here and there (on stackoverflow) Bu I cant get this to work.

How can I read the last value form a txt file (temper.txt) in to the shell script?

txt file:

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Domoticz server
SERVER="192.168.0.30:8080"

# IDX DHT
# The number of the IDX in the list of peripherals
DHTIDX="1"



# temp file with the counting
TMPFILE="/var/tmp/temper.txt"

# old piece of the script. not used
#sudo nice -20 Adafruit_DHT 2302 $DHTPIN > $TMPFILE

# 5 seconds for testing
sleep 5

# piece of the script where I want to read the last value form the TEMPFILE!
PULS=$(cat $TMPFILE|grep .... last value... |awk '.... last value ....' |sed -r 's/^.*=//' |  sed -r 's/\*//')


echo "PULS: $PULS"

# send data
curl -s -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://$SERVER/json.htm?type=command&param=udevice&idx=$DHTIDX&nvalue=0&svalue=$PULS"
PULS=""

#rm $TMPFILE
exit 0
fi
echo "CPT: $cpt"
cpt=$(($cpt+1))
done
exit 1
```

Comment: you can just use tail

Comment: @rikket, Please don't post the answers in your question by editing it. If any of the posted answers helped you, upvote/accept them otherwise answer your own question in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -1 <filename>` will output the last line in the file. If by `last value` you mean the `last line` then this will work.

Comment: Not sure why there was a negative on this.

Comment: @jkdba, all answers were downvoted :D I think others deleted their answers :D